# Writing a Stop condition in Anylogic

Tags: conditional-statements, savechanges, anylogic

I am new in anylogic, and I want to write a stop condition for the simulation and then save the final values:
I have some stocks and flows and I want that when one of my stock values reaches a specific value, the simulation stop and then saves all the values;

1. where should I write the condition?
2. what is the statement for stopping simulation in this case?
3. how can I save the values?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Several places are possible. Easiest is probably a recurring event on the Main that checks the condition every suitable time unit.
2. try this:

`if (myStock > myMaxValue) {
         getEngine().stop(); // you can also use .finish(), see help to decide which is better for you
}`

3. again, several options. Probably easiest to store them into the build-in database (which you can ask to be written to an external Excel at the end of the model). Suggest you read around it in the help, it is quite easy to setup and store data there.

cheers

Comment: Tnx for your help :)

Comment: I wanna write this 
if ( root.ag1 < 0.5)
       getEngine().pause();
I make an experiment, and write it  in the after simulation part, but nothing happen !

Comment: you need to write it somewhere in the model, ideally into an Event that lives on Main (as per my reply). Check out the help to understand what experiments are for and how they differ from the actual model :-)

Comment: Thanks, I get my answer and the problem is solved.:)

Comment: I would not recommend to create a recurrent event for stopping condition. You can write this condition on exit or on enter of any agent to any block in your simulation which would give you a real-time control on the simulation run time.

Comment: I found adding the line getEngine().pause(); in event | action code (as per Benjamin's suggestion above) just after initialising a set of stocks was great way to get a 'clean' screen, i.e. for a presentation slide.